# Checkbox click event firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables inside a modal. From that table I have a column in which it contains checkboxes. The first attempt in getting values of the checked checkboxes is all ok. However, when I close the modal and choose again, the checkbox click event is firing twice. Here is my code:

```
//handle event for checkbox checking.
arresting_officers_table.on("change", ":checkbox", function() { 
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log('Adding!'); //this log fires twice when clicking only 1 checkbox
    //alert('checked! ' + $(this).attr('data-value'));
    arresting_officers_ids.push($(this).attr('data-value'));
    arresting_officers_names.push($(this).attr('data-name'));
  } else {
    //remove item
    var idx = arresting_officers_ids.indexOf($(this).attr('data-value'));
    arresting_officers_ids.splice(idx, 1);
    arresting_officers_names.splice(idx, 1);
  }
});
```

Your response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use below code. add `.off("change")` before attach event.

read more about [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Remove an event handler.

I assume you attach change event every time when model box is open.

```
arresting_officers_table.off("change").on("change", ":checkbox", function() { 
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log('Adding!'); //this log fires twice when clicking only 1 checkbox
    //alert('checked! ' + $(this).attr('data-value'));
    arresting_officers_ids.push($(this).attr('data-value'));
    arresting_officers_names.push($(this).attr('data-name'));
  } else {
    //remove item
    var idx = arresting_officers_ids.indexOf($(this).attr('data-value'));
    arresting_officers_ids.splice(idx, 1);
    arresting_officers_names.splice(idx, 1);
  }
});
```

> other option is attach event every time you can use `Event Delegation`
>   to attach event to dynamic generated element . you can read more about
>   [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
>
> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Comment: @JCFrane you can check what off(). do .everytime you open model box your code attach change event to check box . .off(). will remove event and .on() again assign event .

Comment: sorry, I just accepted it now. Beginner in using stackoverflow =) TY again.

Comment: :) any time .. Happy to help you